# Shell script to pack multiple tar files (depending on the day)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I have some tar files (always increase everyday), for example:

```
1.tar
2.tar
3.tar
4.tar
…
```

I want to wait until it reaches `7.tar`, `14.tar`, `28.tar` and continues, so if possible in the shell script we can arrange the tar to execute packing the files into single unit (tar) as automatically (for ex: every 7 days tar do packing)?

Comment: For automatically do the job, see `cron`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You need to clarify your question.  One item is simple: you say 'every 7 days' but your example mentions 7, 14, 28.  Did 21 get omitted accidentally, or is 56 the next number in the sequence, or what?  Next, is there a separate script generating the numbered tar files, or is that part of your packing script's work?  When the script needs to pack files, does it pack `1.tar`..`7.tar` into `week-1.tar`, and `8.tar`..`14.tar` into `week-2.tar`?  Should you be using dates instead of numbers?  How do you know when a packing has been done?

Comment: …and, finally for now, what does 'packing' mean?  Do you need to extract the files from the 7 tar files to be packed into a (new, temporary) directory, then tar the combined directory?  Or are you just compressing older tar files after they've been around for a week? Or what?  (If it is compressing after a week, then I recommend compressing at the time of creation.  Decompression is very cheap, even during the first week.)

Answer (score 0):

```
last=`ls [0-9]*.tar | sed s/.tar//g | sort -g | tail -1`
if(($last%7==0))
then
     tar tar -cf `date '+%b%d'`.tar [1-9]*.tar
fi
```

Add it to the login script and would automatically packages everything the next log in after 7.tar,14.tar etc are created.

What it does?

```
last=`ls [0-9]*.tar | sed s/.tar//g | sort -g | tail -1`
```

lists the files, remove the ending .tar, sort and take the last file name, which would be the most recently created file. If that filename is a multiple of 7, then packages the entire thing to a tar file named as monthdate, ie today it woudl by Sept24.tar